# Why can't I ping pc1 of subnet 1 from pc0 of subnet 0？

Tags: networking, cisco, subnet

pc0(192.168.0.3/24) connect to the interface0(192.168.0.2/24),and the its default gateway is 192.168.0.2;

pc1 connect to the interface1(192.168.1.3/24),and the pc1's default gateway is not set;

I thought that pc0 could ping pc1, but it could not.
Then I set pc1's gateway to 192.168.1.2,and I succeed to ping pc1 from pc0.

Why do I need set the gateway of pc1?

[As shown in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvkYC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need the replies.

If you ping from pc0 to pc1, this is more or less what happens:

- pc0 will check if the address of pc1 is in the directly connected subnet
- Because pc1 is not in the directly connected network, pc0 will send the ICMP-echo request to the gateway.
- Upon receiving the packet, the router does some routing and delivers the packet to pc1
- pc1 formulates an appropriate response (ICMP echo reply) and sends it to pc0
- First, pc1 will look whether pc0 is in the directly connected network.
- Because pc0 is not in the directly connected network, pc1 will send the ICMP-echo request to the gateway
- when there is no gateway, pc1 does no longer know what to do with this packet and will drop the packet
- If there is a gateway, the reply is sent to the gateway, routing-stuff and delivered to pc0